# Getting "The link you followed has expired" when adding custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, nonce

EDIT: I have completely rewritten this question because it has been closed as off-topic. In my opinion, it has two very relevant points that could help other developers but, in its original form, these points are not too clear. Therefore, I have cut out all of the background information that I now know to be irrelevant to the solution. I have also edited my answer so it is complete (previously, some of the answer was in an update to the question).

I am developing a plugin that creates a custom post type (CPT). My CPT uses a meta box for custom metadata. I create a nonce in the function that displays the meta box. The function that saves the custom metadata and checks the nonce (via `check_admin_referer`) is invoked by the `save_post` hook. When I try to add a post of my CPT I am getting "The link you followed has expired" whenever I click on *Add New*.

Comment: sorry, but there is no such thing as expired links or child post types in wordpress. You should revert your changes from a backup and ask for guidance from the authors of the plugins and theme you use.

Comment: @MarkKaplun, please reread my question. I said nothing about child post types. I mentioned a "child post" (i.e. one that has a parent) which is a thing in WordPress for hierarchical post types. I also said that I am developing the plugin, so I cannot ask the author. I also said I am using a standard theme with only minor amendments and adding a post of my CPT worked with those amendments in place. Please also search for ""The link you followed has expired" WordPress". When I do I see 656 results. I am not the only to have this problem. Most suggest deactivating all other plugins, which I tried

Comment: oh I knew they changed that text, didn't imagine it was changed so badly :(. Anyway, if your issue is with nonce verfification, maybe it will be a good idea to ask about that and remove all the non relevant verbage

Comment: @MarkKaplun, I have rewritten the question and answer. Please reconsider the relevance of this question.

Answer (score 6):

The "The link you followed has expired" message is in the function wp_nonce_ays on line 2607 of wp-includes/functions.php. Apparently, the message was changed from "Are you sure you want to do this?" in 4.9.5. The wp_nonce_ays function is called by check_admin_referer if the nonce check fails. This is the only place in the Wordpress code where this message is used. Therefore, if you ever see this message, you know that a nonce check is failing somewhere in your code.

When saving custom metadata, use the post_updated hook , rather than the save_post hook. For some reason, the save_post hook is invoked when a create post page is shown (i.e. before anything is saved). At this point the nonce has not been created, so the nonce check fails.

Comment: Because of this post I went to the WP docs to get more info on nonce and solved my issue, thanks https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces