# “The link you followed has expired” when previewing a post

Tags: nonce

Recently, I believe after switching to WP 5, **non admin users** are randomly getting the following error when previewing a post:

“The link you followed has expired” . Please try again

[image]

I am suspecting this is due to some conflicts with the theme or some plugins. Unfortunately the theme is not supported. I am aware that it would be wise to switch to a supported theme, but in the meanwhile, where should I start investigating? This [similar post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/302138/getting-the-link-you-followed-has-expired-when-adding-custom-post), points out some trouble with nonces...

Comment: I'd like to know why this post deserves to be closed....thanks guys

Comment: Hey Ricardo,  I can see several reasons for the vote close suggestions.  1: you have not explained anything you've tried to do to fix 2:  you mention it's a custom theme (why isn't it supported?)

Comment: You may try to disable some custom options. I had the same problem and turns out it was caused by metaboxes generated by Titan Framework (probably related to non-ASCII names and IDs of form fields - they're generated from fields labels).

Comment: Yes! That did it! Please use this as answer, I will select as the accepted reply! BTW I'd love to get rid of the Titan framework!

Answer (score 0):

I get it a few time on my Hostnoc hosting, it happens when you have something running at the back of your WordPress (i.e. cron job or schedule backup up etc), this happens when you put a lot of usage on the server. Make sure you save each and everything before pressing publish.

Furthermore, changed the values in cPanel, in the server, but you can do it in the php.ini file:

upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300

Comment: I have updated my question. The error is thrown on post preview