# How to use the wpsnonce clone post link?

Tags: php, jquery, links, nonce

I have this link from a CPT, to clone a post, in this case `post=30808`:

`https://domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?action=duplicate_post_clone&post=30808&_wpnonce=240f0078e7`

Now, I need to use this within a jquery script like this:

```
    $('body.post-type-pessoas .page-title-action').replaceWith( '<a href="https://domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?action=duplicate_post_clone&post=30808&_wpnonce=240f0078e7" class="page-title-action">Clonar Modelo PESSOA</a>' );
});
```

(this will replace the "New Post" button with "Clonar Modelo PESSOA" with the same link)

The thing is that after several days the link won't work because of the wpsnonce lifetime. I don't want to remove the wpsnonce lifetime due to security issues.

My question is how do I get the correct and actualized link?

Thank you.

AMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [`wp_add_inline_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) to inline the action url to the page source. This can be done for example on the [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) action.

In the example below I used [`admin_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/admin_url/) with [`wp_nonce_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_url/) to retrieve the nonce wp-admin url and then added the query paramters to it with [`add_query_arg()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/).

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_action_url', 5 );
function my_admin_action_url() {
    $actionUrl = add_query_arg([
        'action' => 'duplicate_post_clone',
        'post' => 30808,
    ], wp_nonce_url( admin_url('admin.php'), 'action' ));

   wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery', "var myAdminActionUrl = '{$actionUrl}';" );
}
```

The url should be now available in your script via the `myAdminActionUrl` variable.

Comment: Thank you Antti. But could you please let me know how do I use that var myAdminActionUrl within my jquery .js file?

Comment: @Horacsio The same way you would use any other variable, e.g. `alert(myAdminActionUrl);` The variable is in the global scope so it is available to any script.

Comment: Thank you for your precious help here. To conclude I've used the jquery var like this: .replaceWith( '<a href="' + myAdminActionUrl  + '">link text</a>' );

Comment: for some reason the wpnonce changes but it results in an expired link! 

 I found with certain users it links to "wp-admin/admin.php?_wpnonce=5c08124c43&action=duplicate_post_clone&post=30808" and mine to "wp-admin/admin.php?action=duplicate_post_clone&post=30808&_wpnonce=4d19a11d48". Why?

Comment: @Horacsio That is rather strange. The expiration might be caused by a failed nonce check, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/302138/getting-the-link-you-followed-has-expired-when-adding-custom-post. You'll need to check the nonce (and action) naming and handling so that there aren't any issues.